# How to query rows grouped by matching string column but only count the most recent row for a specific set of keywords?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, aggregate-functions

Have a single table of email events where each row is keyed with a specific outgoing email record fk and a specific recipient user fk. At any given time and in no specific order and even simultaneously from different threads I can have new records dropping into this table. Here are the relevant columns...

```
id (pk), email_id (fk), user_id (fk), event (string/name), created_at
```

I am calculating the overall event counts for a given email, like how many emails were delivered, how many bounced, etc. However I need to ignore specific combinations of email events for a specific user because they become outdated when a newer event comes in. For example if a row says the email was 'deferred' for a specific user but then later a new event row is inserted that says 'delivered' or 'bounced' then I only want the most recently added row of any of those related keywords to be counted once as the current state.

What's a good way to do this at read time? I am having trouble because of the multiple layers of grouping that I need to do and reaching the limits of my SQL chops, here is the query I am trying to enhance as described:

```
select `event`, COUNT(1) as count, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as unique_count
from `email_activity`
where `email_id` = 7518
group by `event`
```

For most of the events I want them all counted without any replacement so grouping by only event is fine in those cases, eg if something was a 'click' or 'open' event just total them up.

However, if there are any number of 'deferred', 'bounced', or 'delivered' events for the same email_id/user_id I only want to count the one with the most recent created_at date and ignore all the older ones.

Example row set (email_id, event, user_id, created_at):

```
7518, "click", 25, 1-20-2021
7518, "click", 73, 1-5-2021
7518, "bounced", 45, 1-19-2021
7518, "deferred", 45, 1-17-2021
7518, "delivered", 19, 1-1-2021
7518, "delivered", 25, 1-1-2021
7518, "delivered", 73, 1-1-2021
```

So the queried count for email 7518 would be:

2 "click", 3 "delivered", and 1 "bounced" as the "deferred" row would be ignored for user 45 since it is older (only "bounced", "deferred", and "delivered" events are part of this "only count the latest" rule, all other event names are always counted).

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: @jarlh what do you think, should I include some sample rows? edit: added some sample rows

Comment: Be aware that dates like that need manipulating before they are put into a `DATE` column.

Comment: Are the `INSERTs` arriving in chronological order?  If so, I _may_ have a reasonably simple solution.

Comment: "the one with the most recent created_at date" -- But there are 3 in your example.  Please tighten up the specifications _and_ the example.  Should the count for those events always be "1"?  Or if the "delivered" occurred on multiple days, only the count for the last day should be used?  Or what?

Comment: @RickJames yeah I am having trouble describing it... there should only be ONE record for a given email_id/user_id combination when any number of events are "bounced", "deferred", or "delivered" (only the most recent one should be selected/counted), for all other event names there can be multiple records counted.

Comment: @RickJames actually that's exactly what this problem is solving, in an old version of the software things are coming in sequential/chronological for the most part and so it does a bunch of heavy lifting to delete things, but in the new version it's all async and concurrent so needs to be faster and I am sure I can do this at read time

Comment: If there are two rows on the same date, which one is prioritized? For example, `bounced` and `deferred` exist on the same date like 2022-02-09, which one will be ignored?

Comment: Regarding sample data and the expected result `So the queried count for email 7518 would be: 2 "click", 3 "delivered", and 1 "bounced" as the "deferred" row would be ignored` conratdicts the rule `"bounced", "deferred", and "delivered" events are part of this "only count the latest" rule`. The rule would ignore "delivered" too as the "bounced" is the latest. Please explain.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? (Would prefer to use CTEs for my answer, which are only in 8+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

If the `WITH` clause and the window functions are available, I prefer to divide the table into two parts, give a proper priority to each row, combine them by using `UNION ALL`, and finally aggregate only rows with the top priority.

```sql
WITH specific_email_activity AS (
    SELECT * FROM email_activity WHERE email_id = 7518
),
specific_email_activity_with_priority AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        1 AS rank_priority
    FROM
        specific_email_activity
    WHERE
        event NOT IN ('deferred', 'bounced', 'delivered')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER () over (PARTITION BY email_id, user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rank_priority
    FROM
        specific_email_activity
    WHERE
        event IN ('deferred', 'bounced', 'delivered')
)
SELECT
    email_id,
    event,
    COUNT(*) AS count_event,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS unique_count_event
FROM
    specific_email_activity_with_priority
WHERE
    rank_priority = 1
GROUP BY
    email_id,
    event
ORDER BY
    email_id,
    event;
```

### Solution 2:

If you can not use the `WITH` clause nor the window functions, then try the following code:

```sql
SELECT
    email_id,
    event,
    COUNT(*) AS count_event,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS unique_count_event
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            email_activity
        WHERE
            email_id = 7518
            AND event NOT IN ('deferred', 'bounced', 'delivered')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            email_activity
        WHERE
            email_id = 7518
            AND event IN ('deferred', 'bounced', 'delivered')
            AND email_activity.created_at = (
                SELECT
                    MAX(created_at)
                FROM
                    email_activity AS ea
                WHERE
                    email_id = 7518
                    AND event IN ('deferred', 'bounced', 'delivered')
                    AND email_id = email_activity.email_id
                    AND user_id = email_activity.user_id
            )
    ) AS t
GROUP BY
    email_id,
    event
ORDER BY
    email_id,
    event;
```

### Output of solution 1 and 2:

| email_id | event | count_event | unique_count_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7518 | bounced | 1 | 1 |
| 7518 | click | 2 | 2 |
| 7518 | delivered | 3 | 3 |

### Note:

- If there are more than one row of the same `user_id` and the same `created_at` where their `event`s are composed of a combination of 'deferred', 'bounced', or 'delivered’, you would get unexpected results. In that case, priority about which one of them should be counted must be clarified. Then, the code must be modified in accordance with that rule.
- If `event` is nullable, it must be clarified how `NULL` is handled in aggregation. Then, the code must be modified in accordance with that rule.

### Sample table creation:

The sample table can be created by the following sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS email_activity(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, email_id INT, user_id INT, event VARCHAR(16), created_at DATE);
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(7518, 'click', 25, '2021-1-20');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(7518, 'click', 73, '2021-1-5');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(7518, 'bounced', 45, '2021-1-19');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(7518, 'deferred', 45, '2021-1-17');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(7518, 'delivered', 19, '2021-1-1');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(7518, 'delivered', 25, '2021-1-1');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(7518, 'delivered', 73,'2021-1-1');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(9999, 'click', 25, '2021-1-20');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(9999, 'click', 73, '2021-1-5');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(9999, 'bounced', 45, '2021-1-19');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(9999, 'deferred', 45, '2021-1-17');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(9999, 'delivered', 19, '2021-1-1');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(9999, 'delivered', 25, '2021-1-1');
INSERT INTO email_activity(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) VALUES(9999, 'delivered', 73,'2021-1-1');
```

Comment: thanks I forgot my current db version doesn't have window functions

Answer (score 0):

I did this in postgres db like below. step 4 is the main query which can be directly used. i have just added initial 3 steps for better understanding of each sub query.

```
    create table email_event(id serial, email_id integer, user_id integer, event varchar(10), created_at date);
    
    insert into email_event(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) values(7518, 'click', 25, '1-20-2021');
    insert into email_event(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) values(7518, 'click', 73, '1-5-2021');
    insert into email_event(email_id, event, user_id, created_at)values(7518, 'bounced', 45, '1-19-2021');
    insert into email_event(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) values(7518, 'deferred', 45, '1-17-2021');
    insert into email_event(email_id, event, user_id, created_at)values(7518, 'delivered', 19, '1-1-2021');
    insert into email_event(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) values(7518, 'delivered', 25, '1-1-2021');
    insert into email_event(email_id, event, user_id, created_at) values(7518, 'delivered', 73, '1-1-2021');
```

1. first we will flag the event category:

   ```
    select email_id, user_id,event, created_at,
    case when event in ('bounced', 'deferred', 'delivered') then 'Y' else 'N' end as pick_latest_flag
    from email_event;
   ```

[image]

2. Then we will group pick_latest_flag and rank them based on user_id and flag.

   ```
    select a.*,
    row_number () over (partition by email_id, user_id, pick_latest_flag order by created_at desc) rn
    from (
    select email_id, user_id,event, created_at,
    case when event in ('bounced', 'deferred', 'delivered') then 'Y' else 'N' end as pick_latest_flag 
    from email_event 
    ) A;
   ```

[image]

3. then we will filter out the pick_latest_flag records based on their row number.

   ```
    select * from (
    select a.*,
    row_number () over (partition by user_id, pick_latest_flag order by created_at desc) rn
    from (
    select email_id, user_id,event, created_at,
    case when event in ('bounced', 'deferred', 'delivered') then 'Y' else 'N' end as pick_latest_flag 
    from email_event 
    ) A 
    ) b where pick_latest_flag = 'N' or (pick_latest_flag = 'Y' and rn = 1);
   ```

[image]

4. in the final step, group them on email_id and event:

   ```
    select email_id, event, count(*) from 
    (
    select * from (
    select a.*,
    row_number () over (partition by user_id, pick_latest_flag order by created_at desc) rn
    from (
    select email_id, user_id,event, created_at,
    case when event in ('bounced', 'deferred', 'delivered') then 'Y' else 'N' end as pick_latest_flag 
    from email_event 
    ) A 
    ) b where pick_latest_flag = 'N' or (pick_latest_flag = 'Y' and rn = 1)
    ) c group by email_id,event order by event;
   ```

[image]

Comment: shoot forgot that I don't have `partition by` in my current version of mariadb

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are passing *email_id* as a parameter, following **query** should be able to give you the intended result-

```
select sum(case when f.user_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) sum_event, f.event
from (select * from email_event e1
       where exists (select id from email_event e2 where e2.email_id = e1.email_id and e2.event = 'deferred')
        and e1.event <> 'deferred') f
 where f.email_id = 7518 group by f.event;
```

**Output** when tested for *email_id = 7518*:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| sum_event |   event   |
+-----------+-----------+
|     2     | click     |
+-----------+-----------+
|     1     | bounced   |
+-----------+-----------+
|     3     | delivered |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

### SQL

```
with cte AS
  (select *
   from `email_activity` ea1
   where `email_id` = 7518
     and `event` not in ('bounced', 'deferred', 'delivered')
      or not exists (select * from `email_activity` ea2
                     where ea2.`user_id` = ea1.`user_id`
                     and ea2.`event` IN ('bounced', 'deferred', 'delivered')
                     and ea2.`created_at` > ea1.`created_at`))
select `event`, COUNT(1) as count, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as unique_count
from cte
group by `event`;
```

### Demo

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=725c38e7068fdd68cfb7315a798bdd7e

### Explanation

The Common Table Expression (CTE) includes all rows where the event type isn't "bounced", "deferred" or "delivered" (i.e. it is "clicked" unless there are any other possibilities I don't know about). It also includes rows where the event type is in that list but there is no newer record with an event type in that list.